# Options to use for the Database Backend Command 'analyze' in msfconsole

Tags: metasploit

I noticed the command `analyze` under Database Backend Commands in msfconsole while trying to analyze a subnet.  `analyze -h` shows usage as such:

```
analyze [OPTIONS] [addr1 addr2 ..]
```

and that's it.

I have searched through rapid7's documentation as well as Offensive Security's Metasploit Unleashed for what those options actually are to no avail.

When I execute `analyze addr1` I get

```
[*] No matching modules found.
```

Not sure what modules I should be loading to use this command or the flags.

Answer (score 0):

There is very poor documentation on this. Fortunately, metasploit is open source:

https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/9b1513fca957c3bacf624491a925bd936a4df3ef/lib/msf/ui/console/command_dispatcher/db/analyze.rb

Options are:

- `-a` "all": return results for a host even if result is blank (same as `-v`)
- `-v` "verbose mode": return results for a host even if result is blank (same as `-a`)
- `-p payload` check for the desired payloads, separated by `,`
- `-h` prints the help text